# plotting DCC results with R

Tags: r, graph, vector

I have been running a dcc garch on R; the results is presented as matrix

[image]

I would like to extract the second column as a vector to plot, with date on the x-axis.
For the moment, if I define 
DCCrho = dccresults$DCC[,2]
then head(DCCrho) yields this:

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6r2z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6r2z.png) 0.9256281

[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6r2z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6r2z.png) 0.9256139

[[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6r2z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6r2z.png) 0.9245794 
...

any help to redefine this as a simple vector of numerical values?
any other option to graph the results of dcc with date on the x-axis?
Thanks a lot!

[image: str(dccresults]

---

While trying this

x <- cbind(DCCrho, com_30[,2])

head(x)

[image]

and this:
 matplot(DCCrho ~ x[,2], x, xaxt = "n", type='l')

yields the following error message:

*"Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  invalid first argument"*

Comment: I think `DCCrho$vec` is a vector of numerical values; try `head` on that. I'm not sure where the date variable is, but you can use `plot` with it and your vector.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: What about `dccresult$DCC[2, ]`? This should extract a second row in list element `DCC` of object `dccresults`. Care to show us `str(dccresults)`?

Comment: I added the str(dccresults) above. 
Indeed the DCCrho$vec are numerical values, but as on the first picture above- they are row-indexed; which is the core of my problem.

Comment: Notice I just change above DDCrho$vec to only DDCrho for brievity.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was a matter of length of the vector; the Date and the DCC results need to be vectors of same length.

One also needs to plot both date and DCCrho as shown below.

```
matplot(com_30$date, DCCrho, xaxt = "n", type='l')
axis(1, com_30$date, format(com_30$date, "%y"), cex.axis = .7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you said, "I would like to extract the second row..." that you actually meant "column", because you did the following: `dccresults$DCC[,2]`  Also, as pointed out by a previous comment, the code isn't reproducible, so it's difficult to propose and answer with certainty.  However, I'll do my best.

You said you wanted DCCrho to be a "simple vector of numerical values".  I'm assuming that this is largely a matter of the way that the values are displayed.  Does `DCCrho = as.vector(dccresults$DCC[,2])` look better?.

As for the error message, I think that it's b/c in `matplot(x,y, ...)`, `x` can't be a formula.  Try `matplot(DCCrho, x[,2])`.

If you just want to plot the DCCrho value across some index, you could try something like the following:

```
Y <- as.vector(dccresults$DCC[,2])
X <- seq_along(Y)
plot(X,Y)
```

Does that work?  Aside from the arbitrary time index, what did you intend to reference as "time"?  I don't see a part of the code that you supplied (e.g., a column in dccresults$DCC) that would be an obvious candidate for use as a "date".

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer; it was hard to present clearly the whole problem on stackoverflow.

Comment: 50 to start Monday with a smile :)